# Problem with Grails g:each tag

Tags: grails, tags, each, gsp

I'm struggling to get a g:each tag to work. What I'm passing to the view is a list of hashmaps (something like this [ [ : ] , [ : ] ]  ).
Each hashmap is of the form [location: somelocation , artist: someartist].
The code is the following:

**CONTROLLER**
in the controller I'm passing the following:

```
[searchedResults : results.searchedResults]
```

**VIEW**

```
<g:each status="i" in="${searchedResults}" var="results">
   if(results.location!=null){
       var point${results.location.id} = new google.maps.LatLng(${results.location.lat}, ${results.location.lng});
       var myMarkerOptions${results.location.id} = {
                          position: point${results.location.id}, 
                          map: map
                         };
       var marker${results.location.id} = new google.maps.Marker(myMarkerOptions${results.location.id});   
   }    
</g:each>
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't work?
Thanks!

Comment: This does not look like valid Groovy... Groovy logic belongs in the controller, the view is simply HTML/javascript/Groovy tags.  If you are using groovy, new dynamic variables are declared using def, not var.  If you are writing javascript, then you need a <script> tag.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You're right I should have made my self more clear in what I was doing. So the <g:each> tag is wrapped in a javascript <script> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GrailsGuy is right in that you can't write groovy code in the body of an each tag like that. But let me try and convert it to something for you, since it looks like your doing some javascript in there as well...I think all you need to fix is your if statement

```
<g:each status="i" in="${searchedResults}" var="results">
  <g:if test="${results.location}">
    //everything else seems like it would work, assuming your javascript
    // code is accurate
  </g:if>
</g:each>
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It works. And that's correct I'm doing some javascript as well, sorry I should have been more specific.